# Cant see 'Revit Rooms' in forge viewer

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a problem that I cannot access the revit model rooms in forge viewer.
I initialize forge and when it loads the geometry I save it in an object

```
 updateViewerState(prevProps) {
        if (
            !prevProps ||
            (this.props.urn && this.props.urn !== prevProps.urn)
        ) {
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                this.props.urn,
                (doc) => this.viewer
                    .loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry())
                    .then((i) => {
                        getAllProperties(this.viewer, this.props.setData);
                    }),
                (code, message, errors) => {
                    console.log(code, message, errors);
                    console.log(code);
                    console.log(message)
                    console.log(errors)
                    toast.error("ERROR loading model")
                    toast.error("Go back and reload the page")

                }
            );
```

My funcion getAllProperties is this >

```
   export function getAllProperties(viewer, setData) {
    var tree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree()
    if (tree === undefined) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            getAllProperties(viewer, setData)
        }, 500)
        return
    }
    var categories = {}
    var promises = []

    tree.enumNodeChildren(tree.getRootId(),function (dbId) {
       
            if (tree.getChildCount(dbId) === 0) {
                var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    viewer.getProperties(dbId, function (props) {
                        var elementData = {
                            dbId: dbId,
                            name: props.name,
                            externalId: props.externalId,
                        }

                        for (var i = 0; i < props.properties.length; i++) {
                            var propDisplayName =
                                props.properties[i].displayName
                            var propDisplayValue =
                                props.properties[i].displayValue

                            // Si el valor es null, no lo procese
                            if (propDisplayValue === null) continue

                            switch (propDisplayName) {
                                case 'Category':
                                    elementData.categoryValue =
                                        props.properties[i].displayValue
                                    // console.log(props.properties[i].displayValue)
```

Why doesn't the 'Revit Rooms' category appear?

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Revit Rooms are only visible in the Revit master views in the viewer, so please ensure you load the master view with the viewer, not normal Revit views.

```js
// Method 1:
const root = viewerDocument.getRoot() ;
const viewables = root.search({'type': 'geometry', 'role': '3d'});
console.log ('Viewables:' , viewables);
const phaseViews = viewables.filter (v => v.data.name === v.data.phaseNames
&& v.getViewableRootPath().includes('08f99ae5-b8be-4f8d-881b-128675723c10'));  // pass the guid
console.log('Master Views:', phaseViews);

// Method 2: if you just have one master view (phase) inside your model.
viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry(true);
```

ref:

- https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/no-room-information-revit-file-when-working-dataviz-extension-viewer
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgW9gBCRrWg

Comment: A Lot of thanks , its work

    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                this.props.urn,
                (doc) => this.viewer
                    .loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry(true))
                    .then((i) => {

Comment: It's great to hear it works on your side! :)